# How can I get bundler to use the tilder operator when the gem version isn't semantic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

As of the writing of this question, the latest `sass-rails` version is [5.0.0.beta1](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/commit/423178729e7b84addcee78b33891644b1fc1705b).

I want to update my Gemfile to use this version but also have it continue to use later releases of `sass-rails` v5 as and when they become available. For the moment, let's assume that I constantly run `bundle update sass-rails` and don't care for the consequences to my app.

I find that `gem 'sass-rails', '>= 5.0'` doesn't work. I get this error:

```
Could not find gem 'sass-rails (>= 5.0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
```

If I fix the version to `=5.0.0.beta1`, I get the update just fine.

How can I set an optimistic constraint right now, so that `bundle update` gives me 5.0.0 when it is released, without my having to change the Gemfile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track but `5.0.0.beta1` is less than 5.0 you'd need your gemfile to have:

`gem 'sass-rails', '>= 5.0.0.beta1'`

Then it will update when 5.0 becomes available :)

Comment: Ha. I guess I assumed that the comparison function for versions is the same as for "ASCII sort order," where the string "5.0.0" would be `<` the string "5.0.0.beta1"

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure now though, this might not work, per [issue #1198 I found on bundler's Github repo](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/1198) - the repo owner said, in May 2011: "If you want to switch to a non-prerelease version of the gem later, you will need to remove the .beta from the end of your version requirement."

Comment: I think that is out of date. To test that I just did a rails new and to show it works I set `gem 'rspec', '>= 3.0.0.beta1' and it installed 3.0.4. (I used rspec since it isn't wasn't already in the gemfile.)